# why 2 vectors are not the same in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have 2 vectors:

```
a = 1.0e-04*[0.110000000000000   0.140000000000000   0.140000000000000   0.140000000000000];
b =         [0.000011000000000   0.000014000000000   0.000014000000000   0.000014000000000];
```

by look at by eyes, it seems similar; but when I use this command:

```
a == b
```

then I got:

```
ans = 
  1×4 logical array  
   0   0   0   0
```

The expectation is:

```
ans = 
      1×4 logical array  
       1   1   1   1
```

Does anyone knows what wrong with this command in the matlab?

Thank you.

Comment: See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: One way to fix it can be `abs(a-b)<1e-15`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither 0.11 nor 1E-4 can be exactly represented in floating point arithmetic. And the product of 2 numbers will introduce an extra error.

[Testing for equality in floating point arithmetic is therefore more complex than it seems.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers are stored with a limited precision according to the IEEE754 conventions (search for this term in the net for further details).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subtracting them? I'm pretty sure this is due to the limited precision of the floating point numbers

Comment: I tried, and I got all zeros, such as: **[ 0.0000000000   -0.0000000000   0.0000000000 0.0000000000   0.0000000000]**

Comment: @phuc nguyen Despite that you have what seems to be a zero vector, it has actually been rounded down.

Comment: @phucnguyen That negative sign in front of one of the numbers should make you suspect that these are not actually zeros. See also the documentation for the `format` command..

Comment: @Envidia: if they are rounded down, anyway to detect those very small numbers (for ex: 0.00000000000000002), I still cant detect them even use the **format long** command